# Getting average from a random duration

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm trying to print the maximum, minimum and average of the duration at the end of this code but i'm not too sure how to store the random duration in a specific array to display it after at the end. Below is the code:

```
public void test(){
 int max;
 int average;
 int min;

    long duration=2;
    try
    {   System.out.println("Bus Needs Cleaning" + "\n");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Bus getting cleaned");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        duration = (long)(Math.random()*20);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);

    }
    catch(InterruptedException iex)
    {
    }

 System.out.println("Cleaner completed cleaning in" + duration + "Seconds");
 System.out.println("Bus Leaves");

 System.out.println("Average Waiting Time: " + average + " | Maximum: "+ max + " | Minimum" + min +"\n");

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

EDIT: There are 5 buses coming in and going out and displaying different durations and they all go through the cleaning phase

Comment: your question and objective are unclear. How can u get max /min and avg of a single number??

Comment: Its just part of my code, but buses keep coming in and they all go through the cleaning phase and at each point it displays a different duration, which i want to make an average out of

Comment: you need to specify how many buses coming and this will run in loop then

Comment: There are 5 buses coming in

Comment: try the code in the answer I have given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this one. as far as I understood

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BusRandom {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new BusRandom().test();
}

public void test() {
    long max = 0;
    double average = 0;
    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    int totalBuses=5;//change accordinly
    List<Long> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
    long duration = 2;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <totalBuses; i++) {
            System.out.println("Bus Needs Cleaning" + "\n");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Bus getting cleaned");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            duration = (long) (Math.random() * 20);
            randomList.add(duration);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration);
            System.out.println("Cleaner completed cleaning in" + duration + "Seconds");
            System.out.println("Bus Leaves");
            max=max>duration?max:duration;
            min=min<duration?min:duration;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
    }
    double sum=0;
    for(long l:randomList){
        sum+=l;
    }
    average=(double) (sum/randomList.size());
    System.out.println("Average Waiting Time: " + average + " | Maximum: " + max + " | Minimum" + min + "\n");

}
}
```

Comment: The max and the average looks like its working but the minimum is always 0

Comment: that's not possible unless there is some modification u have made in code or some random is actually zero which again possible because you have taken duration as long so if let say the value from random is produced as 0.04 something then on multiplication with 20 it will be 0.8 but since it's long it won't take the values as 0.8 but 0 so you should take double for duration too

Comment: Alright i'll try and go through the code again! Thank you so much

Comment: don't forget to mention the final result if it helps and do accept ;) Thanks

Comment: Managed to fix it! Thanks again, i will. Can you please upvote my post?

Comment: I can do that but this actually I shouldn't. If the ansr solved your prblm don't forget to accept

Comment: Umm im new here may i know why?